# How to solve this trigonomectric equation $2^{\lvert\sin x\rvert} + 2^{\lvert\cos x\rvert} = 3$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization

I thought its solutions are $(\sin x;\cos x) = \{(\pm1;0),(0;\pm 1)\}$

But how can I solve it?

Please help :(

Comment: Hint: For an idea, try to graph it.

Comment: The solutions are $k\frac{\pi}{2},\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$ by direct exploration. There is no algebraic way to solve this equation

Answer (score 4):

Give the periodicity and symmetries of the trig functions, it suffices to show that $f(u)=2^u+2^{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$ is increasing for $0\lt u\le1/\sqrt2$.  That will imply that the only solutions to $2^{|\sin x|}+2^{|\cos x|}=3$ occur at multiples of $\pi/2$.

We have

$$f'(u)=\ln2\left(2^u-{u\over\sqrt{1-u^2}}2^{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\right)$$

so it's enough to show that

$${2^u\over u}\gt{2^{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\over\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

for $0\lt u\lt1/\sqrt2$. But notice that in this range we actually have $0\lt u\lt1/\sqrt2\lt\sqrt{1-u^2}\lt1$ (i.e., $0\lt\sin x\lt1/\sqrt2\lt\cos x\lt1$ for $0\lt x\lt\pi/4$). So we need only prove that the function $g(u)=2^u/u$ is decreasing for $0\lt u\lt1$. This is equivalent to showing that $h(u)=(\ln2)u-\ln u$ is decreasing on the same range, which is clear since

$$h'(u)=\ln2-{1\over u}\lt0\iff0\lt u\lt{1\over\ln 2}$$

and $\ln2\lt1$.

Comment: (+1) I restored an accidentally omitted square-root sign. Your answer is more straightforward than mine.

Comment: @JohnBentin, thank you!

Comment: Excuse me, please help me explain why $h(u) = \ln2 u - \ln u$

Comment: @PhướcVinh, $h(u)=\ln(g(u))$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto f(x):=2^{|\!\cos x|}+2^{|\!\sin x|}$ is periodic with period $\frac12\pi$. Also clear is that $f(0)=f(\frac12\pi)=3$, and $f(x)\equiv f(\frac12\pi-x)$. So we look to see if there are any solutions to $f(x)=3$ in the range $0<x<\frac12\pi$. It is convenient to transform the variable by writing $t:=x-\frac14\pi$ and $\alpha:=\frac12\surd2\ln2$, so that our function takes the form $$f(x)=g(t):=2\exp(\alpha\cos t)\cosh(\alpha\sin t)\quad(-\tfrac14\pi\leqslant t\leqslant\tfrac14\pi).$$Differentiation gives $$g'(t)=2\alpha[\cos t\sinh(\alpha\sin t)-\sin t\cosh(\alpha\sin t)]\exp(\alpha\cos t),$$from which it is clear that $f'(t)=0$ only when $$\tan t=\tanh(\alpha\sin t).$$Now $\sin$ is concave in the interval $[0\;\pmb,\,\frac14\pi]$ and $\tanh$ is concave in $[0\;\pmb,\,\infty)$, so the RHS of the above equation is concave in $[0\;\pmb,\,\frac14\pi]$ too ; at the same time, $\tan$ is convex in the same interval. So there is no solution to the equation beyond $0$ in the interval. By a similar argument, with convexity and concavity interchanged, there is no solution in $[-\frac14\pi\;\pmb,\,0)$ either. Thus $g$ has just the one stationary point at $0$, namely when $g(0)=2\mathrm e^\alpha\approx3.265>3$. Therefore $g$ decreases from this maximum at $0$ to a minimum value of $3$ at $\pm\frac14\pi$.

It follows that the only solutions to the equation $f(x)=3$ are of the form $x=\frac12k\pi\; (k\in\Bbb Z).$

Answer (score -1):

For simplicity we have to solve for $x\ge 0$ $$f(x)=2^x+2^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=3$$.

Note that $$f'(x)=2^x\log 2-\frac{2^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\log 2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

if   $x\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ then $x\le \sqrt{1-x^2}$
then we have

**Lemma**: $$\frac{2^x}{x}\ge \frac{2^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

**proof**: show that $g(x)=\frac{2^x}{x}$ is decreasing in given interval.

From this lemma it follows that $f'(x)\ge 0$.Thus for all $x\in (0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]$ :$f(x)>f(0)=3$

Similarly prove that $f(x)$ is decreasing for all $x\in [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1]$ hence deduce that $f(x)>f(1)=3$ for all $x\in [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1)$.

The conclusion is now obvious:i.e $x=0,x=1$ are the only solutions.

Comment: Your $x$ are not the $x$ of the original question. The solutions of the original question are $x=k\frac{\pi}{2}$ as I wrote in my twice downvoted answer. Furthermore why all the lemma gibberish? The solutions are $x=0,x=1$, it is obvius. Too bad that you are solving a different equation

Comment: @Raffaele yes i know that i replaced |sinx| by x ,  i left that for the OP to fill in

Comment: And why my solution was downvoted TWICE? Without any comment

Comment: @Raffaele i think you had to prove why they were the only solutions.OP has already guessed that

Comment: My solution is almost the same as @Datboi without the useless derivative thing

Comment: @Raffaele agreed Datboi's method does not help but isn,t my solution correct

Comment: Your "solution" is cheating because you already knew the solutions. Try and solve this $3^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x}=4$

Comment: @Raffaele even if the OP hadnt said it, it is still an easy guess following $2+1=3$,

Comment: Try and solve this $3^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x}=4$

Comment: @Raffaele if one goes off like that there are many unsolved problems by hand,this problem has been asked due to the elegance of its solution (i think)

Comment: @Raffaele also in response to 'cheating' many functional equations get solved by first spotting any obvious solution and then proving that no more exist.If that is also called cheating...i dont know

Comment: I exaggerated, sorry

Comment: I have deleted my answer in response to  comments like "does not help" and "useless derivative thing"

Comment: @DatBoi so, that was my opinion maybe your solution was good and i was blind not to guess your idea.That shouldnt make you delete your answer.If ytou are convinced keep it!